# How to regex datatables filterfn?

Tags: regex, datatables

```
$("#mediaTable").dataTable().fnFilter('0', 2 );
$("#mediaTable").dataTable().fnFilter('1', 2 );
```

I have these two filters that are working properly. I'm trying to add a filter to get matches that match either a 1 or 2, i.e. [12]. For some reason, I cannot get it working.

I've tried:

```
$("#mediaTable").dataTable().fnFilter('[12]', 2, true );
$("#mediaTable").dataTable().fnFilter('^[12]$', 2, true );
$("#mediaTable").dataTable().fnFilter('/[12]/', 2, true );
$("#mediaTable").dataTable().fnFilter('(1|2)', 2, true );
```

All of them return all three values (0, 1, and 2) - I don't want 0 values!

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your test inputs.  You say "return all three values (1, 2, and 3)" but I don't see what test case 3 is.

Comment: What kind of programming language are you using?

Comment: Javascript w/ Rails in the backend, but this is purely a javascript-related problem

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
$("#mediaTable").dataTable().fnFilter('1|2', 2, true );
```

Comment: Why should it do it? According to the OP's forth example, which uses the similar `(1|2)`, it doesn't.